# Calculating Expiry Date with vectors

Tags: c++, datetime, text-files

I have 2 vectors which i read from `.txt` file

```
vector<string> productionDate;  //This vector holds production date as strings in Format''DD.MM.YYY"
vector<int> shelfLife; // This vector holds shelf life in months
```

Since I read them from `.txt` file by columns, `shelfLife[i]` value is equal to `productionDate[i]` value's, like pairs

My question is that, how can I calculate expiry date? I have to add `shelfLife` vector's element to `productionDate`'s month part, and i guess extract from today's time to  calculate if they are expired or not.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well I am very new to c++'s syntax , i know what would i do in c# but in c++ i dont even know where to begin

Comment: Then you should start by reading about `strptime` and `mktime`

Comment: You might want to take a look at `std::time`. Other than that, it is always useful to write proper classes when working in an OOP language. A vector over string might exist temporarily while you read in your text file, but after the reading process is over, you shouldn't have strings to represent time. You should have some object that does that. `std::time` would be fine for that, but you could also write your own, like a class that contains three integer values for the production date, and might even be one that also has the shelf life and has the expiration date as a method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the strings, e.g. like that:

```html
char str[] = "21.12.021";
int day, month, year;
sscanf(str, "%2d.%2d.%3d",
       &month,
       &day,
       &year);
```

From here you can either use simple math or a library for operations on dates, such as: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: My strings are in vector , how can i pass them in to char ?

Comment: after getting a string from your vector, you can just call `str.data()` to get the char * which can be passed to sscanf

Comment: By using transform() I have converted string vector to char vector , and in for loop i have scanned your str[i], but how can i access month part ? how can i do mathematical calculations with that variable?

Comment: I recommend learning a bit more about the language before trying to solve concrete problems. Here is a great book: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/